# How to make a stateful widget rebuild?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have a stateful widget called Square (chess). I call setstate on various properties of it, but it doesn't update onscreen unless I do a hot reload.

```dart
class Square extends StatefulWidget {
  Square({
    this.address,
    this.piece,
    this.color,
    this.onPressed,
    this.selected = false,
  });
  String address;
  Piece piece;
  Color color;
  Function onPressed;
  bool selected;

  @override
  _SquareState createState() => _SquareState();
}

class _SquareState extends State<Square> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:
          RawMaterialButton(onPressed: widget.onPressed, child: widget.piece),
      color: widget.selected == true ? kSelectedSquareColor : widget.color,
    );
  }
}
```

In the same file, I go through the arduous process of manually creating 64, compiling these 64 in 8 lists of 8, then passing them to a list called board. Here's an example of the square objects:

```dart
Square(address: 'A8', piece: blackRook, color: kWhiteSquares)
```

Then, I make a grid:

```dart
class _ChessBoardState extends State<ChessBoard> {
  List<List> board = startingSetup;
  bool turn = true;
  Square selected;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 5,
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 8,
        children: List.generate(
          64,
          (index) {
            Square square = board[index ~/ 8][index % 8];
            square.onPressed = () {
              if (selected == null) {
                // shorter for you
              } else if (square == selected) {
                // shorter for you
              } else {
                print('three');
                setState(() {
                  selected.selected = false;
                  Piece p = selected.piece;
                  square.piece = p;
                  selected.piece = null;
                  selected = null;
                });
              }
            };
            return square;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have omitted the if and else if for your sanity. All conditions work, but only display on screen after I hot reload. Why doesn't the widget rebuild automatically when I call setState? It should, shouldn't it, when, for instance, the setState is called on square.piece and a new piece is added?

Comment: I believe what you're doing is you're doing setState for the square widget itself whereas what you need is to setstate for the chessBoard widget. To validate that what I suggest is adding a floating action button in the chessBoard and making its on pressed a setState, if that worked then I believe you need to then through some [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) approach handle the setStates of the board widget

Comment: Some of the set states do apply to it, though. For instance, calling                   `selected.selected = false;` updates the selected property of the chessboard, as does `selected = null;`, doesn't it?